# Trigger email if cell changed in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet where we track department metrics in Google Sheets.  I am trying to get it to email when a metric changes.  I am using counta (in range P2) to monitor if a new metric came in and I want to trigger an email if a value in the range changes.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var value = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("P2").getValue().toString();
  var last = ScriptProperties.getProperty("last");

  if(value != last) 

  {
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("last",value);
  MailApp.sendEmail("dave@mydomain.com", "cell P2 changed",
    "new value: " + value + "\n\n" + ss.getUrl())
  }
}
```

I have trending charts and ultimately I'd like to email the actual trending chart is changed (a new monthly value is entered) but I thought I'd walk before I ran.  :)

Comment: I deleted my comments since you debugged your code!!!  Just add a timer trigger (as Srik says) and change the function name because it is not an onEdit function anymore :-)

Comment: Thank you Serge.  I must have tried editing this script a 1000 times yesterday before it dawned on me that I need to really do these things on a timed basis.  Thanks for your help yesterday with the script.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you get it all working now...:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells that change because of a formula do not qualify as an 'edit' to trigger the onEdit function. 
You should either monitor the source cell(s) (if  they are edited manually) or the second alternative is to have a function running under a trigger that runs every minute (or whatever frequency you like) and send out the email. 
The function you've written looks good to be run under a trigger.

Comment: Since I actually have the person inputting data in another sheet because I don't want them to blow up this one that generates gauges and charts for Intranet pages, I realize that I can't do this on edit and should do it via a timed script.  I appreciate the advise Srik.

Answer (score 0):

Dave Lalande. Take a look at this code.

```
function getTimeEditRange(Range){
  return YourFunction(Range);
}
```

If the value is the same, then the event will not happen.

Best regards!