# Iterate a function through several rows in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Here is the script I have written.  It puts a time stamp at the end of the row whenever that row is edited.

```
function setDate() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //Get Active cell
      var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
      var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
      var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
  //Check to see if column is A or B to trigger
      if (cellcol == EDITMECOLUMN)
      {
  //check for row to trigger
        if (cellrow == EDITMEROW)
        {
  //Find cell and set date in a defined cell
      var celldate = sheet.getRange(EDITMEROW, EDITMECOLUMN);
      celldate.setValue(new Date());
  //end set date
        }
      }
 }
```

It works well, but how can I change it so it iterates for each row instead of me having to copy the script for each row manually?  I have a form that populates a spreadsheet, and the "latest" results from each topic in the form are put in a report spreadsheet.  I need the column time stamps for each row because each row represents a topic from the form, and the form user can choose to skip sections for weeks at a time.

EDITMExx pieces are just spots where I would put column or row #.

The function is called from a onEdit() trigger

Comment: More information is needed before a rational answer can be provided. What is EDITMEx? How are you calling this `setDate()`? Is it an onEdit trigger function, a custom spreadsheet function, or something else? What use case do you need to resolve that would put a timestamp on multiple rows for a single edit? Add more information to this question, please.

Comment: Further information has been added, thanks.

Comment: I think we're getting thrown off by the word 'iterates'. Do you mean that you want a timestamp *on each row when that row is edited*, or do you want a timestamp *repeated on every row when any row is edited*?

Comment: The first one, I want a timestamp on each row when that row is edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling this function from an onEdit trigger, you can (should!) take advantage of the Event that is generated to know where to put the timestamp. (See [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events).)

You state that you place a timestamp "whenever that row is edited". I'll assume that the timestamp column is fixed, like so: `var TIMESTAMP = xx`, where xx is the column number.

```
/**
 * onEdit function to place timestamp in a specified column
 * when an edit is made in a row.
 * 
 * @param {Event Object} event  Information about the event
 *                              that caused this function to
 *                              be triggered.
 */
function setDate(event) {
  var TIMESTAMP = 5;   // Column number for timestamp
  var HEADER_ROWS = 1; // # of header rows to skip monitoring

  var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var changedRow = changedRange.getRow();

  //Logger.log("Edited range:" + changedRange.getA1Notation());
  if (changedRow > HEADER_ROWS) {
    ss.getRange(changedRow,TIMESTAMP).setValue(new Date());
  }
  // else do nothing
}
```

This is a pretty basic onEdit function, with just one conditional check - it avoids timestamping your headers. You can add other tests to monitor a subset of columns, specific sheets, and so on. Knowing what objects are passed in the Event parameter will help you imagine other possibilities.

**Warning:** There are lots of ways that you can miss changes to your spreadsheet. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234631/1677912) for more information.

If you're new to Apps Script triggers, see [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas) for debugging tips.

Comment: Sorry, one issue I realized I still have with this.  It works perfectly when I am directly editing a cell, but let's say that cell B1 is set to =D1.  When I edit cell D1, cell B1 is changed, but the date is not updated for row B.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, but in that case you didn't edit row B, the content changed due to a formula - [one of the things that don't get picked up by onEdit triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14794528/1677912). One thing you can do, if that's the behavior you want, is to maintain two copies of every row's contents - the one in the spreadsheet, and a second "old" copy - and then on ANY change, iterate over all rows looking for content changes and marking them.

Comment: ...For a small sheet, this would be ok, but would make edits very very slow for even a modest size of data. Another idea, you could build and maintain a map of formula relationships, and walk through that on every change to note which cells are updated. Less data-intensive, but more computationally complex. I guess what I'm saying is that you're not going to be able to rely on an onEdit trigger to mark formula changes.

Comment: "you could build and maintain a map of formula relationships, and walk through that on every change to note which cells are updated."  What would this option look like?

Would it be something like, a formula with an if statement to see if the "history" cell equaled the "formula-edited cell" and if not it would set the value of the current date?

Comment: Kind of... I was imagining that you'd `getFormulas()` on the whole spreadsheet, and parse those to determine cell relationships. From that, create a table that would tell you "if D changes, B will change". Then, when onEdit tells you D changed, you'd know to timestamp B as well. Sounds easy - but for a general solution this would be very, very tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Create a for-loop (or any kind of loop) that will iterate through all your rows.  Something like:

```
var numRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for(var i=0; i<numRows; i++){
    data[i][someColumnWhereYouWantDateSet].setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Where in my function should I put the for-loop?  I tried within the if statement but that did not work.