# Google Docs script to email someone when a cell colour is changed

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to set up a google spreadsheet that will email someone a generic email when a cell in the document is coloured. The cells to be coloured will all be in one column and the persons email will be in another column. It is to be set up as an agenda so that once one agenda item is complete, the cell is coloured, colouring the cell would then email the person who's item is a couple of items down the agenda to allow them time to attend the meeting.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What have *you* tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To send the email, you'll need to use the Mail Service:

[Mail App Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

You can research the cell change trigger by reading a post like this:

[Trigger Email if Cell Changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791777/trigger-email-if-cell-changed-in-google-sheet)